# Is there a rolling 7 day formula for Google sheets that will sum up the figures in one column based on dates in another column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the below formula which in theory should work but it adds in additional numbers giving an incorrect figure.

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!F3:F, Sheet1!B3:B, "<="&TODAY()-3, Sheet1!B3:B, ">="&TODAY()-10)
```

My dates (yyyy-mm-dd) are in column B and my figures are in column F.

I want this to provide the total sales figure for a rolling 7 days but to have a 3 day delay.

I have attached my example workbook: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1koU28NWl9T0D2Pip0caa1tWXrAeQFHtjgEz1a1kngvI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share sample data and desired result.

Comment: Please find example workbook attached: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1koU28NWl9T0D2Pip0caa1tWXrAeQFHtjgEz1a1kngvI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

your formula should be:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!F2:F, Sheet1!B2:B, "<="&TODAY()-3, Sheet1!B2:B, ">="&TODAY()-9)
```

&

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!F6:F, Sheet1!B6:B, "<="&TODAY()-3, Sheet1!B6:B, ">="&TODAY()-9)
```

you can test the output with filter like:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!B2:F, Sheet1!B2:B<=TODAY()-3, Sheet1!B2:B>=TODAY()-9)
```

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't fix the error.